# How to pass state from one useEffect to another useEffect on intial page load?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a component which displays products for a category. CategoryId is taken from subscribe method which is formed by pubsub pattern so I am waiting sub function to finish and passing to my API but it is not working on intial load of the page?

```
import { subscribe } from "./pubsub";

const Test = () => {
  const [productId, setProductId] = useState({});
  const [response, setResponse] = useState([]);
 
  React.useEffect(() => {
   function sub() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    subscribe("product-message", (data) => {
      // console.log("Got some message", data);
      // setProductId(data.productId);
      resolve(data.productId);
    });
  });
}
    async function fetchData() {
      let message = await sub();
      let response = await fetch(
        `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/${message.productId}` // Here I couldn't get the async data from above useEffect
      );
      console.log(response);
      setResponse(response);
    }
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return <div>{response.title}</div>; //It is not printing in intial load
};
export default Test;
```

So here is my sandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-forest-to9pz?file=/src/test.jsx

Comment: what do you mean by passing the state? the state is already shared

Comment: @MajidParvin  want to get the  data to 2 nd useEffect when it is set 1 useEffect (the data is asynchronous here).

Comment: since you have `productId ` as the effect of the second one, it should trigger automatically

Comment: @Majid Parvin It will trigger but it will not call at first instance. So the question is like this how can I get productId from subscribe method and pass it to my api call at intial page render?

Answer (score 0):

If you only need the response, you do not need to store productId in state and then use it in another useEffeect to fetch data. You can simply implement the logic in one useEffec. Also note that you need to use the json response from fetch call so you need to use it like

```
  let response = await fetch(
    `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/${productId}`
  ).then(res => res.json());
```

or

```
 let res = await fetch(
    `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/${productId}`
  )
 let response = await res.json();
```

Complete function will look like

```
const Test = () => {
  const [response, setResponse] = useState([]);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData(productId) {
      let response = await fetch(
        `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/${productId}`
      ).then(res => res.json());
      console.log(response);
      setResponse(response);
    }
    console.log("Api calls");
    subscribe("product-message", (data) => {
      // console.log("Got some message", data);
      fetchData(data.productId);
    });
  }, []);


  return <div>{response.title}</div>;
};
export default Test;
```

However if you need productId in your application, you can go via a multiple useEffect approach like you have tried in your sandbox. Also make sure that you are using thee fetch call correctly and also make sure to not make the API call wheen productId is not available

```
const Test = () => {
  const [productId, setProductId] = useState({});
  const [response, setResponse] = useState([]);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Api calls");
    subscribe("product-message", (data) => {
      // console.log("Got some message", data);
      setProductId(data.productId);
    });
  }, []);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      const res = await fetch(
        `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/${productId}` // Here I couldn't get the async data from above useEffect
      );
      const response = await res.json();
      console.log(response);
      setResponse(response);
    }
    if(productId) {
        fetchData();
    }
  }, [productId]);

  return <div>{response.title}</div>;
};
export default Test;
```

[Working Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/interesting-meninsky-6z8if)

Comment: Thank you for your timre.Unable to load data on intial page load.Can you help me on that.because I am using subscribe which will work async and unable to pass productId at intial page renders.